# Fluent NHibernate and Stored Procedures

Tags: nhibernate, stored-procedures, fluent-nhibernate, hbm

I have a basic Customer/Order/OrderItem/Product object graph.  Customer has Many Orders, Order has Many Order Items, Product has many Order Items.  These are successfully mapped using FNH.

I've hit a snag with configuring a stored procedure & fluent-nhibernate.  There is not a native way to map stored procedures in fluent-hibernate FNH (version 1.0 RTM).  There was a solution [here](http://maonet.wordpress.com/2009/05/06/create-your-own-parts-to-merge-stored-procedure-into-fluent-nhibernate-mappings/) about adding parts to class mappings but the AddPart call has been taken out of the release of FNH.

The stored procedure is simple:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[OrderCountByCustomer] 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        c.name as [Customer.Name],
        CAST(count(o.id) as NVARCHAR) as [Customer.OrderCount]
    FROM customer c
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [order] o
        ON o.customer_id = c.id
    GROUP BY c.name

END
```

There's a CustomerOrderSummary.hbm.xml in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="NVAble.Orders.Core" namespace="NVAble.Orders.Core">
    <sql-query name="OrderSummary">
        <return class="CustomerOrderSummary">
            <return-property column="Customer.Name" name="CustomerName" />
            <return-property column="Customer.OrderCount" name="OrderCount" /> 
        </return>
        EXEC [OrderCountByCustomer]
    </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Here is the CustomerOrderSummary class def:

```
namespace NVAble.Orders.Core
{
    public class CustomerOrderSummary
    {
        virtual public string CustomerName { get; set; }
        virtual public string OrderCount { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", CustomerName, OrderCount);
        }
    }
}
```

However, when try to start a NH session i get error in named query `OrderSummary` with no other details.

I'm probably missing something really simple that maps the `CustomerOrderSummary` class to the procedure, I don't know. That domain object obviously doesn't map directly to a table in the data base so I'm unsure if having a normal `<class />` HBM mapping would work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I did format the code, looked ok in the preview, fubared in the post.  Most annoying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so after a bit more investigation.  I needed a mapping for the Domain Class as well as a named query hbm.xml file.

In my configure class i have

```
config.Mappings(x =>
{
    x.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<CustomerMapping>().ExportTo(schemaPath);
    x.HbmMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<CustomerOrderSummary>();
});
```

Only downside is that I need to manually create the xml mapping for the stored procedure, I can't use FNH at the current time